# Calling a function that returns a typealias value inside another function

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement, type-alias

Currently we have a class with a function that returns a typeAlias as a value:

```
class NotificationDetailFactory {

   typealias T = UIViewController & NotificationDetailType

    func getNotificationType(notificationType:PushNotificationDetail?) -> T? {

        switch notificationType?.type! {
        case .notice:
            let notificationVC = NoticeViewController()
            notificationVC.notificationType = notificationType
            return notificationVC
        case .promotion:
            let promotionVC = PromoViewController()
            promotionVC.notificationType = notificationType
            return promotionVC
}
}
```

The return values in the switch statement are what need to be accessed (ie, notificationVC, promotionVC).  In a view controller the "getNotifcationType" function is being called:

```
 let factory = NotificationDetailFactory()

 func goToDetailView(notificationType: PushNotificationDetail) {

        switch factory.getNotificationType(notificationType: notificationType){

        case  notificationVC:
            self.presentViewController("BGMDetailNotifications", nextModule: "notice", showInNavigationController: true, showContainer: false, data: [:], animation: nil)
        case paymentVC:
            self.presentViewController("BGMDetailNotifications", nextModule: "payment", showInNavigationController: true, showContainer: false, data: [:], animation: nil)
} }
```

The problem that is occurring is when we try to compile the project, an error pops up next to each case statement in the 2nd portion of code that reads:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'notificationVC'

where the VC is whatever VC is trying to be accessed in the  getNotificationType function.  My guess its acting this way because its returning a typAlias for the first function.  Whats the best way to access these VCs from the first function?

Comment: This code is very confusing. Why is `notificationType` optional if you then crash if it's nil? What do you expect `case notificationVC` to do? (What *is* `notificationVC`? Is that a type? Types should have leading capitals. Is it a value? Where is that value defined?) This compiler error has nothing to do with using a typealias. Your naming suggests you're returning a type, but you actually return an instance. It's very unclear what you're trying to do here.

Comment: the notificationVC is the viewController that needs to be returned.  Based on the 2nd portion of code the switch statement will use the result of the first portion of code to determine which viewController to go to in the "presentViewController" function.

Comment: @  Rob Napier, the return of T is there because its a viewController that conforms to a protocol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check their types.

```
let vc = factory.getNotificationType(notificationType: notificationType)
switch vc {
    case is NoticeViewController:
        self.present(vc, nextModule: "notice", ...)
        // here goes your code for NoticeViewController case
    case is PromoViewController:
        self.present(vc, nextModule: "payment", ...)
        // here goes your code for PromoViewController case
}
```

Comment: although as @RobNapier said in the comments, this code is very very complex!! I think it's good to try another approach...

Comment: This is correct to achieve the stated goal, but this approach is deeply broken. If you need to introspect the type of the thing returned, then returning a protocol is pointless. the `notice` or `payment` values should just be properties of the view controller (exposed via the protocol).

Comment: @RobNapier totally agree with you. The whole ideology of Generic is to code in a way that you don't need to check their types. (MAYBE MAYBE MAYBE only in production nights that you have like less than hours to deliver the code :D, but I'm strongly against it myself)